# Apollo cache typePolicies: same field on multiple parents/queries

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo, apollo-client

I have the same fields on multiple parents (different objects) in Apollo cache.

I want to do some logic in the merge function in `typePolicies`.

However, when these fields are repeated on many places coming from different queries, I find myself having to repeat code like this:

```
typePolicies: {
    RiesgoComercialAbr: {
      fields: {
        situacion: {
          merge(existing = [], incoming = [], { variables }) {
            debugger;
            return incoming;
          },
        },
        posicionamiento: {
          merge(existing = [], incoming = [], { variables }) {
            debugger;
            return incoming;
          },
        },
        ratingRiesgoCese: {
          merge(existing = [], incoming = [], { variables }) {
            debugger;
            return incoming;
          },
        },
        scoreLiquidez: {
          merge(existing = [], incoming = [], { variables }) {
            debugger;
            return incoming;
          },
        },
      },
    },
    RiesgoComercialAut: {
      fields: {
        situacion: {
          merge(existing = [], incoming = [], { variables }) {
            debugger;
            return incoming;
          },
        },
        posicionamiento: {
          merge(existing = [], incoming = [], { variables }) {
            debugger;
            return incoming;
          },
        },
        ratingRiesgoCese: {
          merge(existing = [], incoming = [], { variables }) {
            debugger;
            return incoming;
          },
        },
        scoreLiquidez: {
          merge(existing = [], incoming = [], { variables }) {
            debugger;
            return incoming;
          },
        },
      },
    },
    RiesgoComercialInf: {
      fields: {
        situacion: {
          merge(existing = [], incoming = [], { variables }) {
            debugger;
            return incoming;
          },
        },
        posicionamiento: {
          merge(existing = [], incoming = [], { variables }) {
            debugger;
            return incoming;
          },
        },
        ratingRiesgoCese: {
          merge(existing = [], incoming = [], { variables }) {
            debugger;
            return incoming;
          },
        },
        scoreLiquidez: {
          merge(existing = [], incoming = [], { variables }) {
            debugger;
            return incoming;
          },
        },
      },
    },
}
```

Is there any way to globally work on these `merge` functions for these fields?

Thank you very much